# Milestone of the Entitlement Process showing the different time that the target time set why?

Tags: apex, casemilestone, entitlements

I have created a `Milestone-1` and `Milestone-2` in a single `Entitlement process`.
I have shown the two screen shots.

[image]

**So, whenever I am checking Time Remaining is not getting decrease and when I checked in Feed details, I see its showing 33 minutes, it was expected to see the 7 minutes or less time.**

Any idea why its happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer [Milestone Recurrence Types](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestone_sequential_recurrence.htm&language=en_US&type=0)

- No Recurrence: This is the option we need if the milestone occurs once, such as our First Response and Fix milestones.
- Independent: This type of milestone start date is only based on the case criteria. If another milestone is created, the start date is based on when the last milestone completed.
- Sequential: This type of milestone start date is based on when the previous milestone’s target date was. For example, if a case enters a sequential milestone at 12:00 and its target date is an hour away at 13:00, but the milestone is actually completed at 12:05, the next milestone is created for 14:00, which is one hour away from the previous milestone’s target date, not the completed date.

According to your use case, define recurrence type as **Independent**.